# UAE visa has incorrect information and visa validity

Tags: visas, uae, visa-expiration

My husband, son, and I applied for Dubai visit visa for a 14 day trip. We didn’t complete the forms ourselves, as it was applied for through a travel agency. We received visas, but my husband's and son's professions are not correct.

Does it make any difference for purposes of a visit? I asked the travel agency and they said it’s just a formality and will not be an issue. Is that correct?

Also, we travel on 13th October and visa is valid until 16th October. Does that mean we can stay for 14 days, as planned, or do we have to leave on the 16th?

I am confused about these two things.

Comment: I’d recommend you check anything completed on your behalf by an agency before submission - in this case it doesn’t matter but you are responsible for the accuracy of the information provided in a visa application.

Answer (score 1):

It’s fine for UAE. Listed profession does not matter one single but for a UAE tourist visa.

Recently I met a person in the UAE who is an Army soldier in his own country and his passport and visa pictures were in uniform but his visa said *Sales Representative*.

I have seen that profession listed countless number of times.

But that short validity is a problem. If your visa is expiring on 16th October then you can not stay for 14 days after 13th of October. Are you reading the dates right?

Comment: Can you give a source for this?

Comment: @RoboKaren i will try to find one, unfortunately I don't have a source right now other than just real life experience with this. I have seen well over a hundred visitor visas with most common profession being Sales Representative, even for someone as young as 4 years.